# Decrypting string with java/kotlin as is done with openssl enc

Tags: java, kotlin, aes

im trying to make an android app with inspiration from a bash script program, but im stuck here:

```
echo MTQ4MjY5 | openssl enc -aes256  -K "3235373436353338353932393338333936373634363632383739383333323838" -iv "34323036393133333738303038313335" -a
```

I need to find a way to encrypt **MTQ4MjY5** in java/kotlin as they do with openssl, but im unable to do so.

I have tried:

UPDATE:
Still returns wrong encrypted string, but getting closer. Any ideas why?

```
 public static byte[]  encrypt(byte[] plainText) throws Exception{

        byte[] key= DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("3235373436353338353932393338333936373634363632383739383333323838");
        byte[] iv= DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("34323036393133333738303038313335");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(key,ALGORITHM);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    }
```

Called like this:

```
val result = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Encrypt.encrypt("MTQ4MjY5".toByteArray()))
```

Wrong output: **PNKLL87lXkHjjYU7yMtObA==**

I have no idea how to solve this, help much appreciated

The correct encrypted string is: **juF+fDAsvFnKIfaXUzMoHQ==**

Comment: The OpenSSL statement does not decrypt, but encrypts. Apart from that, key and IV hex are encoded in the statement.

Comment: Thank you, this has led me on the right path as i thought i was decrypting all along lol. So many wasted hours. I'm getting closer, but still getting wrong output

Comment: (1) there is no `String.toByteArray()` method; do you mean `.getBytes([charset])`? (2) the value encrypted by `openssl` includes a newline; in Java source use `"MTQ4MjY5\n"`

Comment: Thank you Dave, the new line fixed the issue!!